# On Load Youtube Video Not Going Fullscreen When Randomized

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, fullscreen

I've looked around a lot and have seen similar questions, but none of the answers worked for me. Right now, my code looks like this:

```
var videos = ["P1DQiS4zvi0", "HocBwQ7wkHk", "J7_r3jl9YA4", "y_C-HYubwuQ",   "BCyKiPLtMIk", "27gzg7TLJJ8", "yuJMIC39Rss", "9UJ7xYXK2cE", "EnwP9T1piq4"];
var choice = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
var html = '<iframe id="video" style="overflow:hidden" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videos[choice] + '?modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&autohide=1&controls=0&vq=hd1080&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
document.write(html);
```

This function in the header makes the video full screen:

```
$(function(){
      $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });

      $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
      });
    });
```

My problem is that the video loads, but it's a small size in the top left corner instead of a fullscreen video. Also, the rest of the webpage doesn't load correctly.

If I take the video HTML out and replace it with a static ID, it works perfectly fine.

I've tried putting the fullscreen function in the same script as the randomizer one with no luck.

I think it's gotta be something with the id (video) not being recognized in the javascript so the function doesn't apply to it. I'm a JS noobie though and don't know exactly how it works.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

order of execution.

You will need to make sure your styling block is executed after the document.write(html);

Alternatively use none-inline styling rule.

```
#video{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 ...
}
```

Comment: I moved the javascript styling to after the randomization and nothing changed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7zLjq1t3/ should work. The html is commented out, but is the video that runs fine when the variable js is commented out. Annndd fiddle doesn't seem to fullscreen videos so you can't exactly see the problem >.<

Comment: jsfiddle does not support document.write, so your example does not run on my browser at all. Here is a codepen which seem to work fine.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wagWmW